# Не могу понять как пользоваться информацией в толковом словаре

Tags: словарь

Есть несколько вопросов,помогите мне, если кто-то может,с ними.
1-Толковый словарь не объясняет значения по всем словам,а показывает  только употребление в контексте?
Пример
Выдать-Дать, предоставить что-н., снабдить чем-н. Запятыми выделяют синонимы,или это что-то другое.Дать и выдать же отличаются по смыслу,зачем они написали в определении(или что это)слово дать,словом предоставить и снабдить кому-то можно объяснить значение?
2.Нас учили морфемам,зачем нам знать о них если я не могу узнать значение приставки вы в слове выдать.
3.разве не лучше бы было знать слова и отличия их от других по морфемам? Пускай хоть частично

**Спасибо всем за ответы.Все очень ценные и мудрые.Некоторые из числа догадок подтвердились,а другие же закрепились в вере что я все правильно понимаю.Ура)**

Comment: "Не могу понять..."  
![Не могу](http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/2//72/298/72298725_Mironov_04b.jpg)

~~~Стеб, и ничего, кроме стеба~~~

Comment: Очень смешно и не избито,помогать то будете?
Чем вас фраза "не могу понять" рассмешила?У вас не было такого хотите сказать?
Не ожидал увидеть здесь насмешку.Я за помощью пришел,а в ответ это.
Как-то задавал в интернете вопрос так мне человек старше 50 отвечал троллингом и насмешками,не пытаясь помочь,в чем и заключается функция форума..

Comment: Помогать буду! Плюс за вопрос для начала)  
Просто сегодня воскресенье... а вопрос Ваш крайне сложный для ответа... народ выжидает... кто первым подставится... а давайте завтра с утречка?

Comment: Давайте завтра,спасибо за отклик.Вопрос да,столько разных переплетений в языке что можно запутаться.Еще труднее объяснить и правильно задать вопрос.Поэтому извиняюсь если что-то не так написал.

Comment: Вы мне когда будете свободны подайте сигнал,и начнём)

Comment: Из предисловия к Ожегову :  
> Словарная статья включает толкование значения, характеристику строения многозначного слова, примеры употребления, сведения о сочетаемости слова, грамматические и акцентологические (в необходимых случаях также орфоэпические) характеристики слова. Словарная статья сопровождается описанием тех фразеологических выражений, которые порождены этим словом либо так или иначе с ним связаны.

Одни слова объясняются другими словами, кратко и внятно. Такова специфика, с давних пор заведенная. Скачайте Словарь Академии Российской 1789-1794 в пдф и читайте, читайте, читайте...

Comment: я тугодум видно,к сожалению не понимаю бывает.степень например это мера,затем пишут сравнительная величина чего-нибудь..как такое держать в памяти...мера и сравни величина это не одно и то же вроде,так что это 2 значения ? Ужас на крыльях ночи если это так(у слова 10 пунктов например если и в каждом по 5-6 таких значений через запятую)...и как это специалисты усваивают?как вы это делаете,волшебники не иначе))Мне так охота научиться и осознать что я делаю не так и как правильно вообще понимать то что пишется в словарике....повторюсь,я такой даун?((

Comment: Так значения слов мы усваивали не по толковому словарю, а читая с раннего детства книги, в общении.  Осознание значения слова для русского человека через толковый словарь - скорее исключение, чем правило. Способ скорее вспомогательный, чем основной. Другое дело, если русский язык для Вас неродной.

Answer (score 1):

1. Толковый словарь кратко даёт определение слова. Дать определение можно через описание значения слова или дать ряд синонимов. И тот и другой метод имеют свои достоинства и недостатки и составители словарей как правило пользуются обоими способами. Слово "выдать", по цитируемому вами БТС под ред. Кузнецова, имеет 8 значений, а "дать" - 11, в некоторых значениях эти слова действительно почти идентичны. Предложения *Выдать под расписку деньги* и *Дать под расписку деньги* по смыслу ничем не отличаются (есть отличия стилистические, но их указывать необязательно).
2. У глагола выдать, помимо приведённого вами примера есть ещё 7 значений, где значение приставки видно лучше.
3. Может и лучше, но главный недостаток такого метода - трудность нахождения слов с приставками (*прибежище* в таком словаре нужно искать на "Б" или на "П"?).

Comment: Спасибо большущее вам,и всем кто отписался,все внесли в оказание мне помощи лепту.Очень помогли,неоценимо.

Answer (score 0):

В каждом словаре есть вводная часть, где описано, для чего он предназначен и как он построен, организация словарной статьи - в частности. Там и справляйтесь.
На конкретные вопросы будем по мере возможности отвечать.

> > 1-Толковый словарь не объясняет значения по всем словам,а показывает только употребление в контексте? Пример Выдать-Дать, предоставить что-н., снабдить чем-н. Запятыми выделяют синонимы,или это что-то другое.Дать и выдать же отличаются по смыслу,зачем они написали в определении(или что это)слово дать,словом предоставить и снабдить кому-то можно объяснить значение?

Толковый словарь как раз объясняет значение, на то он и толковый.

> 2.Нас учили морфемам,зачем нам знать о них если я не могу узнать значение приставки вы в слове выдать.

Можете. Узнавайте.

> 3.разве не лучше бы было знать слова и отличия их от других по морфемам? Пускай хоть частично

Тоже не возбраняется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,учту)